# Can we send desktop/push notification using Google Sheet?

Tags: push-notification, google-sheets, notifications, google-sheets-api

Is there any possibility to use some desktop/pop-up or push notification useing google sheet and =NOW() parametr? I would like to have some task remainder. In rows there are information like 1) current time [=NOW()] 2) schedule time 3) what to do. if 1st and 2nd row are the same i receive some notification/alert that scheduled task should be started

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported by Sheets API per se. Try playing around with [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API) and see how you can implement it in your app. You also need a mechanism that constantly checks for the values every second which calls for a real-time app implementation.